# Show text from textarea in a div JS

Tags: html, jquery, onkeyup

As in title, I would like to see what I'm writing by input text.

There is my code:

```js
function setLogo(txtLogo){
    //edit logo by textarea
    var myLogo = $("#title-logo");
    myLogo.text(txtLogo);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtLogo" onkeyup="setLogo(this)" value="Logo Text">
<h2 id="title-logo"></h2>
```

When I'm writing I can see `[object HTMLInputElement]` inside `h2` but if I'm not writing nothing I can't see nothing on it. Any ideas?

Comment: so read the value.... You are referencing the element

Comment: jQuery solution without inline code: `$('#txtLogo').on('input', function () { $('#title-logo').text($(this).val()); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to set the object `txtLogo` as text, but instead its `value`.

```js
function setLogo(txtLogo){
    //edit logo by textarea
    var myLogo = $("#title-logo");
    myLogo.text(txtLogo.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtLogo" onkeyup="setLogo(this)" value="Logo Text">
<h2 id="title-logo"></h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you are passing an element. But you need to pass the *text value* of this element. You can solve this problem in two ways.

Add the **value** parameter to `txtLogo`. It should be like this:

```
myLogo.text(txtLogo.value);
```

Or you can write the same parameter for `this`, in event **onkeyup**, inside the `<input>` tag. Like this:

```
onkeyup="setLogo(this.value)"
```